# PJAX listen to pjax:end event with standard js

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, pjax

So github uses "defunkt's" PJAX module (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events), and I'm making a firefox addon that needs to listen to the event pjax:end

So far I can do it with jquery like this:

```
$(document).on('pjax:end', function (t) {
   console.log('pjax:end');
})
```

however how do I do this with standard javascript functions?

```
document.addEventListener('pjax:end',function(){
     console.log('ya');
}, true);
```

does not work.

for those who know firefox-addons this code code does not work:

```
gBrowser.contentWindow.wrappedJSObject['$'](gBrowser.contentDocument).on('pjax:end', function (t) {
    Cu.reportError('pjax:end');
})
```

it throws this error:

```
/*
Exception: Permission denied to access property 'guid'
te.event.add@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:2
e.event.add@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:3
.on/<@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:2
.each@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:1
te.prototype.each@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:1
.on@https://github.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/frameworks-752c70f2b89dcf2d1f948637afa35a3285fe6424.js:2
@Scratchpad/2:1
*/
```

Comment: It is odd, I am trying to write an extension to work with GitHub too, and I do have jQuery, yet even your first example doesn't work for me. Does it still work for you, or may be GitHub changed something?

Comment: Yeah it works still, what I ended up doing was injecting a script into the page that added a jQuery listener that triggered a function from my addon. The addon is here: [ghForkable](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghforkable/) let me know if you need more help. Btw nice job on searching up and finding this topic, its exactly where you need to look to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware its not currently possible to catch jQuery events using native JavaScript (although looking at this bug ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11047 it appears that there are some library's that would enable this, but not without code changes to the PJAX code).

Comment: much thanks for that man! ill use the bind function, test it out then come back and let you know how it worked

Comment: i tried `document.bind('custom', function(event) ` but it doesnt work, is it possible to use w3c bind to get that custom trigger?

Comment: Looking at the test jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Jqeza/3/ it appears the test is only with the jQuery bind method (rather than the w3c one). I suspect your best bet may be to try and figure out how to get firefox to talk to githubs jQuery "/

Comment: messed around lots I couldn't get it to work with standard js :(