# addEventListener doesn't work with colon (:) in event name

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, pjax

I'm currently trying to get a `pjax:complete` event handler to work. Below I've sketched the situation:

I'm working on a Chrome extension for GitHub, it does not contain jQuery, and I don't want to include it. I do want to listen for the pjax event, and do something when it happens. However, the example below only seems to work when using jQuery's `$.on` function. I've also created a simple JSFiddle for this, without using the real pjax events, but simulating it. [You can find that here.](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Lv1hdf/1/) If you run it, you'll see the jQuery eventhandler called 2 times, but the VanillaJS one only once.

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function () {
    console.log('jQuery pjax event is called');
});

document.addEventListener('pjax:complete', function () {
    console.log('VanillaJS pjax event is called');
});

document.dispatchEvent((new Event('pjax:complete'))); // This works
$(document).trigger('pjax:complete'); // this doesn't (FYI: actual function used can be found [here][1])
```

The desired result is that the VanillaJS event is called even when it's called from jQuery.

1: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/blob/master/jquery.pjax.js#L181

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem with a [minimal, complete verified example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/); at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or with a '[Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1)' here in your question?

Comment: 1) You're using `complete` and `completed` inconsistently in your example. 2) The colon doesn't make any difference in behavior -- that's what happens when using any event name.

Comment: @apsillers I don't think so, I've fixed the different references

Comment: @DavidThomas, problem is that it requires the real pjax events, which I'm unable to reproduce using JS Fiddle or equivalent.

Comment: @DavidThomas I've added a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem as close as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720367/pjax-listen-to-pjaxend-event-with-standard-js) already answers mine. It's not possible using VanillaJS.